# Get class name from appending two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my HTML code I have multiple images with class names of img0, img1, img2 and so-on.

What I want to do is give each of these some JavaScript code. I have made a for loop in my JavaScript to loop as many times as there are images on the page. However, I don't seem to be able to append two values to make a class name and I'm pretty sure I've done it before.

Here is my JavaScript code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numitems = $(".img").length();

    for (var i = 0; i < numitems; i++) {
        $(".img" + i).css("margin-left", ((100 - $(".img" + i).width()/2))+"px");
        $(".img" + i).css("margin-top", ((100 - $(".img" + i).height()/2))+"px");
    }
}
```

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: first problem seems to be selector `$(".img").length()` it won't return anything if the class names are `img1, img2...`

Comment: then what is the method `getClass(".img" + i)` it should be `$(".img" + i)`

Comment: Don't use incremental attributes. It always ends up in a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @ArunPJohny the getClass was a mistake. Shouldn't have been there.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I'm making it like that as I have underlying PHP code that takes images from a folder to display on a page.

Comment: @Georgewb13 that's still no reason for incremental attributes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Fair enough, but how would you suggest I do it?

Comment: @Georgewb13 without seeing exactly what you're trying to achieve. From the look of the cumulative margin, I'd suggest `float: left;` instead and a common class between all items.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hmT97/

Comment: Ahh, thanks. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the class names at all. Use `this` as an object reference:

```
$(".img").each(function() {
      $(this).css("margin-left", ((100 - $(this).width()/2))+"px");
      ...
}}
```